# Windows 10 Insider Activation Error

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation, windows-insider

I recently upgraded to **Windows Insider 20H1** and I am getting an error
where it shows that Windows will expire but in the **Control Panel** it shows that **Windows** is activated.

Please help me.

[image: Windows 10 Insider Non-Updated]

> **Update** @Jhon told me to update my **Windows 10 Insider**

> Here is the updated image

[image: Windows 10 Insider Updated]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I am getting an error where it shows that Windows will expire

That's not an error it is a warning.

**What Happens When a Windows 10 Build Expires?**

> This only applies to unstable Insider Preview versions of Windows 10.
> Stable versions of Windows 10 will never “expire” and stop working,
> even when Microsoft stops updating them with security patches.
>
> When a build of Windows 10 expires, Microsoft says you will see a
> warning that you’re using an expired build. The warning will reappear
> once per day, and you will also see UAC (User Access Control)
> warnings. Previous reports have said that Windows 10 will reboot every
> three hours after it expires, so Microsoft may have made the
> expiration process less annoying.

...

> Microsoft expires these builds to prevent people from staying with
> old, unstable versions of Windows 10. These builds of Windows 10 are
> made available for testing, and there’s no point in testing an old
> build that has a bunch of already-fixed bugs.

...

> You should update to a newer Insider build of Windows 10 (or go back
> to a previous stable build) before the expiration date.

Source: [How to Check When Your Windows 10 Build is Expiring](https://www.howtogeek.com/396873/how-to-check-when-your-windows-10-build-is-expiring/)

Further Reading:

- [Complete list of Windows Insider builds released after the Spring / April Creators Update and what happens when a build reaches its expiration date](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install-insiderplat_pc/complete-list-of-windows-insider-builds-released/2168f950-3418-4694-8b95-23f68db2bcf7)

Comment: But when ever I try to update I get a blue screen

Comment: @Arib.Glitch That is a different question. Please ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the Insider Agreement?  The Insider versions expire. In fact, V2004 Insider 20H1 is practically the same as what is now in production.

You should be upgrading to 20H2.

Activation, and build lifetime (Insider build) are two different things. Your build may expire but your activation does not.

You must keep builds up to date. I see new ones about monthly.

My current build is 19645.1